# Undestanding Ember Route hooks to redirect

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have this router setup

```
this.route('dashboard', function () {
    this.route('numbers');
    this.route('workspaces', function () {
        this.route('workspace', {path: '/:wid'});
});
```

dashboard.workspaces is a link in navigation bar. When you click it loads dashboard.workspaces.workspace and immediately redirects to first subnav. I do it like this:

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({

     model: function() {
         return this.modelFor('dashboard');
     },

     afterModel: function(model) {
         this.transitionTo('dashboard.workspaces.workspace', model.get('workspaces.firstObject.id'));
     }
}
```

It's all good except when I'm already on dashboard.workspaces.workspace route and click dashboard.workspaces then "afterModel" hook is not called and I end up on dashboard.workspaces, which is unwanted empty page. Are there other hook that would be always called? I have already tried "activate" and few others with no luck.

Would be also nice to be able to save last subnav transition and redirect to in when click on main nav.

Comment: As far as I remember, `beforeModel` will be called everytime. But what you trying to do, why do you have a link to dashboard.workspaces in navbar?

Comment: Gennady beforeModel called just once for sure. I need in main navigation link to dashboard.workspaces which will unfold to dashboard.workspaces.workspace tabs in other part of the page.  Each tab will have a separate page.

Comment: None of the route hooks are hit when you are already on the route and just removing child routes from the page

Comment: and unless your model hook is doing something different than calling the store using the id, you might as well use the model in your transition instead of the id

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So it's important to think of the router as a stack.  As you visit routes you push a route on/off the stack.  An item that is being pushed on or off the stack will have events fired correlating to the transition at hand.

In your particular case, the current implementation has two issues. The one issue you've already mentioned, when you pop off children routes the parent route doesn't fire any events.  The second issue would occur under these circumstances.

1. Navigate to workspaces `/workspaces` (it redirects to the first workspace `/workspaces/1`)
2. Navigate to the second workspace `/workspaces/2`
3. Refresh the page while on `/workspaces/2` (while it's in the `afterModel` hook of workspaces it redirects to the first workspace `/workspaces/1`)

So the easiest way to handle this is to create a child route under the `workspaces` route whose sole purpose is to redirect to the first workspace.

```
this.route('dashboard', function () {
    this.route('numbers');
    this.route('workspaces', function () {
        this.route('first');
        this.route('workspace', {path: '/:wid'});
});
```

Remove the `afterModel` logic from the `workspaces` route and put it in the `workspaces.first` route.

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  redirect: function() {
     var first = this.modelFor('workspaces').get('firstObject');
     this.transitionTo('dashboard.workspaces.workspace', first);
  }
}
```

Now in your template, instead of ever pointing to `workspaces` you would point to `workspaces.first`.

```
{{link-to 'Workspaces' 'dashboard.workspaces.first'}}
```

Now when you are in the dashboard and click it, it will push on the `workspaces` route into the stack execute its hooks.  It will then push the `first` route onto the stack and execute its hooks.  The hooks of the `first` route will cause it to pop the `first` route off the stack and push the `workspace` route onto the stack.  When you try to click the `workspaces` route again it will pop `workspace` off the stack and then push `first` back onto the stack which will then again execute its hooks.

Example: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/cipawapali/edit?html,js,output

Comment: not sure if I understand. Seems "workspaces.foo" functionally will be a copy-paste of workspaces route

Comment: Correct, the difference is you will never stay on the route, it will never have children, so every time you visit the route the hooks will be fired.

Comment: @Kingpin2k But the nav link (to `dashboard.workspaces.first`) will no longer have the `active` class when you are in the `dashboard.workspaces.workspace` route, right?

Answer (score 1):

May be a bit late, but for anyone looking for a solution to this empty white page as I was.

Ember provides an implicit/hidden route, that can be used instead of creating a new one, which is pretty good for this.
In this question's case it would be `DashboardWorkspacesIndexRoute`, no need to declare it in the router, just add the route file with the redirection you want

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
    redirect() {
       let first = this.modelFor('workspaces').get('firstObject');
       this.replaceWith('dashboard.workspaces.workspace', first);
    }
}
```

You can then use `{{link-to 'Workspaces' 'dashboard.workspaces'}}` and it will retain the `active` class while still redirecting every time.

For more information, [here's the source](https://emberigniter.com/redirect-to-default-subroute/).

Comment: I won't hurt to end sentences with a period even at the end of a paragraph.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I'll take it into consideration